# Use bash shell with wamp on windows

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, cmd, wamp

I'm working on local website hosting by WAMP and i'm trying to execute bash command with exec or system functions but it only works with cmd or powershell command cause i'm on windows.

Is there a way to force bash interpretation ?

Thank you.

Comment: Bash is a Linux command interpreter. There are ports of bash to Windows. Either download and use one of the ports or convert the shell script to PowerShell.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for your time. I have to develop an application for a unix server so the PowerShell conversion is not possible. And I'm sorry but I'm not a computer expert... So I don't really know what solutions I have with the bash ports... May you guide me toward more precise idea or documentation please ?

Comment: If you are developing an application for a Unix server, then you need a Unix server or a virtual machine of one. Windows and Unix are very different operating systems. By Unix, do you actually mean Linux? Take a look into running Linux as a virtualized OS on Windows.

Comment: @JohnHanley , sorry for the late answer. I totally understood what you meant. So I decided to install LAMP on the WSL of my computer. Now I'm facing new problems... You look really experienced. Maybe you could help me ? I post my question at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232435/how-to-download-ppa-through-proxy-on-debian-wsl). About this question, maybe you could answering that is not possible and I will mark it as correct. Thank you for your time again!