# How to download PPA through proxy on Debian WSL?

Tags: proxy, debian, apt

I am trying to download/install php7.2 on Debian which is installed on my WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), through my company's proxy.

I have been able to download apt packages by using this solution : https://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy

The problem now is that I need ppa from `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` cause php > 7.0 is not available anymore with `sudo apt-get install` and I tried many solutions but no one worked for me. Every solution tested by the asker of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361213/unable-to-add-gpg-key-with-apt-key-behind-a-proxy were tried and the answers too.

So, there is my last obstacle :

```
$ sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
Co-installable PHP versions: PHP 5.6, PHP 7.x and most requested extensions are included. Only 
Supported Versions of PHP (http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for Supported Ubuntu Releases 
(https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are provided. Don't ask for end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu 
release, they won't be provided.

Debian oldstable and stable packages are provided as well: https://deb.sury.org/#debian-dpa

You can get more information about the packages at https://deb.sury.org

BUGS&FEATURES: This PPA now has a issue tracker:
https://deb.sury.org/#bug-reporting

CAVEATS:
1. If you are using php-gearman, you need to add ppa:ondrej/pkg-gearman
2. If you are using apache2, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/apache2
3. If you are using nginx, you are advise to add ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline
   or ppa:ondrej/nginx

PLEASE READ: If you like my work and want to give me a little motivation, please consider donating 
regularly: https://donate.sury.org/

WARNING: add-apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales, see
https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56 for workaround:

# LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
More info: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpw9sj_dvp/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
```